# Eclipse Mars.2 (4.5.2) Problems opening an editor

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc

This is the estructure of my maven project

```
myProj
├── myProjFunctionalTests
|   ├── src
|        └── main
|             └── java
|                   └── com
├── myProjEar   
├── myProjWeb  
├── target
└── pom.xml
```

When I open a JAVA file from myProjFunctionalTests with F3 I got this error:

```
Problems opening an editor.
Reason:
myProj does not exist
```

and in the Project References of **myProj** I ckecked **myProjEar** and **myProjWeb**

Comment: What kind of file? It can make a difference.

Comment: the file is a java file

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this? I have the same problem.